# Scattergraph in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am not sure if this is the right site, though here's my question:

I've been trying to make a scattergraph with Excel, but not getting the result I want. I have 2 data values for one thing. I don't want them to display two different dots for both data values, I want to have one dot, but with the name of the thing. To make myself more clear, here's what I currently have:

[image]

And this is kinda what I want: (but then also the names by the dots)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A XY scatter plot is correct.  When you highlight the data and select scatter plot it will assume some things.  In your case, you want to "switch row/column" in the data values page.  In 2007+, you can select chart tools --> design and then "switch row/column".  Once that is done go back to edit the data and change the X values and Y values to their own value.
[image]

Comment: I get this: http://piclair.com/v3164
For some reason it does that, why and how can I solve this? Do I need to change something in settings? (BTW, Excel sees the countries as series. Could that be the problem, and if so, how to change?)

Comment: Yup.  That is what I got at first too.  You will need to right click on the plot area --> Select Data.  For each country series edit place the life expectancy on the X value and the birth rate on the Y value.  You need to do it for each series.  Excel isn't smart enough to do it for us.

Comment: Yes, that works! Now lastly, do you know how I can get a name on the X and Y axes? (Life expectancy/Birth rate)

Comment: Nevermind, I looked it up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TutorialPoint If you want to add the labels from Column A to your data points (rather than just in the legend) let me know.